# WPF Listview with GridView for formatting. Formatting Disappears on Scroll

Tags: c#, wpf

I am looping through each item in a listview and formatting the text boxes in the grid view.  The initial format works, but then formatting disappears if I scroll the listview up and down a couple of times.

This is the basic loop to work through my items:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lvDocumentation.Items.Count; i++)
{
    // Grabs the item 
    ListBoxItem selectedListBoxItem = lvDocumentation.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(lvDocumentation.Items[i]) as ListBoxItem;

   PersonDTO thisPersonDTO = (PersonDTO)lvDocumentation.Items[i];        

   // I do some odds and ends here and call formatting routines for the buttons... 

}
```

Later after I do some checking on thisPersonDTO, I format the selectedListBoxItem depending on the persons status

```
        // Textblock
        foreach (var item in UiCommon.FindVisualChildren<TextBlock>(selectedListBoxItem))
        {
            if (item.Name.ToLower() == textblockName.ToLower())
            {
                if (docPresent)
                {
                    //item.Background = backgroundColor;
                    item.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
                }
                else
                {
                    ((TextBlock)item).Foreground = Brushes.Red;
                }
            }
        }

        // Button 
        foreach (var item in UiCommon.FindVisualChildren<Button>(selectedListBoxItem))
        {
            if (item.Name.ToLower() == buttonName.ToLower())
            {
                if (item.GetType().Name == "Button")
                {
                    if (docPresent)
                    {
                        //item.Background = backgroundColor;
                        item.IsEnabled = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //item.Background = backgroundColor;
                        ((Button)item).IsEnabled = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

That code works and the formatting is done correctly (as long as the listBoxItem is in the display, but that's another story)

Once the process is completed button colors are set.

If I scroll up and down a bit the colors revert to their original formatting and I can't figure out why.  I have breakpoints everywhere, but don't see any code executing.

I realize that there are formatting issues when I try to format listboxitems that are not yet displayed.  I use this bit of code for that:

```
lvDocumentation.UpdateLayout();
lvDocumentation.ScrollIntoView(lvDocumentation.Items[index]);
selectedListBoxItem = lvDocumentation.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(lvDocumentation.Items[index]) as ListBoxItem;
```

That gets me the listbox item rather than null if the item originally returned null because it was not in the display area.

Something seems to be refreshing the formatting, but no clue why / where?

Comment: ListView uses UI Virtualization, meaning that it only renders the things visible on the current view and that code behind method could only find those. My suggestion, do not apply by calling that code once (or multiple times every scroll), but set the ListView's ItemTemplate and bind IsEnabled to your property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I scroll up and down a bit the colors revert to their original formatting and I can't figure out why.

It's because of the default UI virtualization and container recycling that is described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-controls).

You may disable the virtualization by setting the attached `IsVirtualizing` property to `false`:

```
VirtualizingPanel.SetIsVirtualizing(lvDocumentation, false);
```

This comes at the expense of the scrolling performance but given your current approach of manipulating the UI containers directly, that's your only option.

You should look into [MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff798384(v=pandp.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). It's *the* recommended design pattern to use when developing XAML based UI applications.